# Fail to uninstall babel-cli with npm

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, babeljs, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to uninstall global babel-cli on my mac os x el capitan and am getting the error messages below.  How can I proceed to completely remove babel-cli?  Can I simply remove the table-cli folder in node_modules?

> npm ERR! error in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/package.json'
>
> npm ERR! extraneous: fsevents /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/fsevents
>
> npm ERR! error in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/fsevents: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/fsevents/package.json'
>
> npm ERR! extraneous: semver-truncate /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/semver-truncate
>
> npm ERR! error in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/semver-truncate: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/semver-truncate/package.json'

Comment: Try to reinstall before uninstalling.

Answer (score 1):

Install Latest version of babel-cli

```
npm install -g @babel/cli@latest
```

then run uninstall command

```
sudo npm uninstall -g @babel/cli
```